# how to get multiple values in onchange using while loop

Tags: php, ajax

i want to get the value from select box using onchange in while loop. but am getting first value only. how to get the values from all?

i just did this by using while loop in php.

Can anyone tell the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Here my code:
Here my code...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser1()
{

var str = document.getElementById("process").value;
var str1 = document.getElementById("snp").value;

alert(str);
alert(str1);

if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
//xmlhttp.open("GET","process.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.open("GET","process.php?q=" + str + "&q1=" + str1, true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
</script>

<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="txtHint">
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="0">
<tr>
<th style="padding-left:500px;">Serial Number</th>
<th>&nbsp;Status</th></tr>

<tr>

<td>
<?php $i = 1;
while ($i <= 10) {
echo $i++;  /* the printed value would be $i before the increment (post-increment) */
?>
<form>
<select name="process" id="process" onchange="showUser1(this.value)">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="0">Not Yet Start</option>
<option value="1">On Process...</option>
<option value="2">On Stock Yard</option>
<option value="3">Despatched</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="snp" id="snp" value="<?php //echo $fetch['serial_number']; ?>" />
</form>
<?php } ?>
</td>
<td id="txtHint1"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: can anyone please tell the solution for this...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have noticed few mistakes in your code.

1. Do not include form in while loop.
2. select box name and id should be dynamic [like process1, process2 .. ]
3. In function showUser1(), you have to pass two parameters.

> onchange="javascript : return showUser1([loop counter], this.value);"

1. Javascript function looks like below

> function showUser1( cnt, processValue)   {
>
> ```
>  var str = processValue;
>
>  var str1 = document.getElementById("snp"+ cnt).value;
>
>  ........   }
> ```

1. Input type text box value should be dynamic as select box.

Comment: dynamic means, i can't understand... how can i keep dynamic value for select box and text box..

Answer (score 0):

> function showUser1(i, processValue)  {
>
> var str = processValue;     var str1 = document.getElementById("snp" +
>   i).value;
>
> alert(str);     alert(str1);
>
> if (str == "") {        document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML =
>   "";       return;     }   if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+,
>   Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();     }
>   else {// code for IE6, IE5        xmlhttp = new
>   ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");   }   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =
>   function() {      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
>             document.getElementById("txtHint1").innerHTML =
>   xmlhttp.responseText;         }   }   //
>   xmlhttp.open("GET","process.php?q="+str,true);    xmlhttp.open("GET",
>   "process.php?q=" + str + "&q1=" + str1, true);    xmlhttp.send();
>
> }
>
> Serial Number
>                      Status
>
> ```
>           <tr>
>
>               <td>
>               <?php $i = 1;
>               while ($i <= 10) {
>                   ?>
>                   <form>
>                       <select name="process<?php echo $i;?>"
>                           id="process<?php echo $i;?>"
>                           onchange="showUser1(<?php echo $i;?>,this.value)">
>                           <option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
>                           <option value="0">Not Yet Start</option>
>                           <option value="1">On Process...</option>
>                           <option value="2">On Stock Yard</option>
>                           <option value="3">Despatched</option>
>                       </select> <input type="text" name="snp<?php echo $i;?>"
>                           id="snp<?php echo $i;?>"
>                           value="<?php //echo $fetch['serial_number']; ?>" />
>                   </form>
>
>
>
>                    <?php  $i++;  /* the printed value would be $i before the increment (post-increment) */  }  ?> </td>
>               <td id="txtHint1"></td>
>           </tr>
>
>       </table>        </td>   </tr> </table>
> ```

Comment: thank you very much for your response. but its not working boss. even i put alert in first line of javascript , but its not working...

Comment: let me know what is the problem?

Comment: Oh God... am getting text box value also... but i didnt get anything from process.php...